# c# datagridview autorefresh in LAN

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, refresh, lan

I am beginner in c# with a huge problem.
An application with datagridview in front (Termin plan for one work day) works on many PC's in LAN with MS Windows Server and with MySQL database.
How can I become the changes made on one workstation AUTOMATICALY on all other PC's WITHOUT any action on them (application only started).
I have a procedure for data and datagridview refresh, I must only know WHEN I must start this procedure, that means I must know WHEN any other workstation made any changes.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a timer and when it elapses you refresh you gridview. so on defined period of time it will be refreshed automatically. the problem can be that if you update to often there's a overload of accessing the db. to prevent this, you could make an serverapplication which handles all data

Let's say PC 1 is starting the client application.

1. First it connects to server application (the server stores the reference of the client e.g. in an list).
2. After that the user on PC1 makes changes and click on save, the software will send the changes to the server (e.g. a custom object with all needed information).
3. Server saves the changes to the DB
4. Serverapplication give a response to the specific client if it worked or not
5. If it worked, Send an custom object (for example named ChangesDoneEvent)  to all clients that indicates that changes have been done.

   6. All connected clients will receive that object and know now that the have to refresh their gridview.

For further information just search for C# Multi threaded Server Socket programming. For sending custom objects over network you will find many resources in the internet too, maybe this will help you [Sending and receiving custom objects using Tcpclient class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316397/sending-and-receiving-custom-objects-using-tcpclient-class-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is there in c# also a possibility to make something as broadcast Messaging - so if one PC made something - the other know that automaticaly.

Comment: maybe you can make use of some libraries. i think with that library you can handle all you want to do: http://www.networkcomms.net/. For making changes probably you should use TCP. for Broadcasting that changes have been made you can use UDP Broadcasts for the network (if all pcs are in the same subnet, easiest and fastest way. but messages can be lost. so maybe one client will not update if packet is loss). Or you can hold all the connected clients in a List and send them a Object like described in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Declare Delegate on your form*

```
public delegate void autocheck();
private System.Timers.Timer TTTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public void autofilldgv()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
      this.Invoke(new autocheck(UpdateControls));
    }
    else
    {
      UpdateControls();
    }
}
private void UpdateControls()
{
   //call your method here
  filldgv();

}
void TTTimer_Elapsed(object sender System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  mymethod();
}
public void mymethod()
{
  //this method is executed by the background worker
  autofilldgv();
}
private void frm_receptionView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.TTTimer.Interval = 1000; //1 sec interval
  this.TTTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TTTimer_Elapsed);
  this.TTTimer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided above is actually a good way to handle this scenario.  Before implementing you might also want to think about the potential fall backs. It is possible that Client PC 's IP could change and since you are using sockets. The object reference added in the list could be faulted state. You might want to think of handling this pitfall.